# JQuery syntax bug on an auto-fill listener and keyup trigger while looping and looking for sequentially named inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops, autofill

So, I am working with (playing with, as I am not an employed developer) many different inputs on a web form. The end game is that they will be posted and saved as a CSV file.

But the immediate question I have is regarding the syntax to loop through names and activate a autofill for adjacent cells

Here is an example code of a single event that works:

```
$(".className").keyup(function(){
    var dataPoint = $(this).val();
    if(!$('[name="this_row_1"]') ==''){
        $('[name="that_row_1"]').val(dataPoint);
    }
});
```

So, when the input with `".className"` is altered, if `"this_row_1"` is not empty, then `"that_row_1"` will be filled with the value of `".className"`.

The code works, but I have many inputs with sequentially named rows; `"this_row_1"` - `"this_row_150"` etc.

What is the correct syntax to incorporate a loop in the `'[name="` type structure?

I have tried variants of this with no success:

```
$(".className").keyup(function(){
    var dataPoint = $(this).val();
    for(var i = 1; i < 151; i++)
    if(!$('[name="this_row_"[i]]') ==''){
        $('[name="that_row_"[i]]').val(dataPoint);
    }
});
```

I am not sure if you can even loop through `'[name="`. And if you can, certainly I have issues placing the loop variable.

Thanks in advance

**Updated:**

Here is an abbreviated, example HTML form code which illustrates the idea a little better:

```
<input class="className" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_1" /><input name="that_row_1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_2" /><input name="that_row_2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_3" /><input name="that_row_3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ( . . . ) -->
    <tr>
        <td><input name="this_row_150" /><input name="that_row_150" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".className").keyup(function() {
    var dataPoint = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 1; i < 151; i++) {
      if ($('[name="this_row_' + i + '"]').val() != '') {
        $('[name="this_row_' + i + '"]').val(dataPoint);
      }
    }
});
```

There were a few issues:

1. with your string concatenation `'[name="this_row_' + i + '"]'`
2. your `if` statement equality check `!=`
3. checking the `.val()` of `$('[name="this_row_' + i + '"]')`

See [Javascript String documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works to populate all of the "that" rows, if even one of the "this" rows is filled.  But I am hoping not to blanket fill all of the "that" rows, but only the "that" input adjecent to the filled "this" input.  ie. those "this" & "that" which lie adjecent to each other in the same row

Comment: @Killuh-B Can you post what the structure of the html tags is?

Comment: @Killuh-B e.g. Where is `.className` in relation to `[name="this_row_N"]`?

Comment: I have updated my question with a base structure of the form, minus some of the fluff

Comment: @Killuh-B - Isn't this currently doing what you are looking for? Every row of the form `that_row_N` is being populated with the value of `.className` if the corresponding `this_row_N` is not filled. Is that not what you are looking to do? **Edit**: Found a bug in your `if` statement. The `!` should be next to the `!=`. See my revised answer. You also want to check the `.val()` of `this_row_N`.

Comment: Perfect!  I see the syntax error now.  I ought to have noticed the .val() problem. thanks for your time!